# Blazor - Fetching from Db Internal Server Error

Tags: c#, .net, blazor, dbcontext

I have a blazor web app (Auto) that fetches items from the db on the client side.
I have already created Services and controllers to fetch all items which works but when i try and search for specific items it breaks and i get this error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).
   at System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()
   at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpClientJsonExtensions.<<FromJsonAsyncCore>g__Core|12_0>d`2[[System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[Design_A_Bear.Models.Item, Design_A_Bear.Models, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]], System.Private.CoreLib, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e],[System.Text.Json.JsonSerializerOptions, System.Text.Json, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51]].MoveNext()
   at Design_A_Bear.Services.ClientItemService.GetItemsByCategory(String category) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Design_A_Bear_2.0\Design_A_Bear.Services\ClientItemService.cs:line 56
   at Design_A_Bear.Client.Pages.Items.Browse.OnInitializedAsync() in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Design_A_Bear_2.0\Design_A_Bear\Design_A_Bear.Client\Pages\Items\Browse.razor:line 49
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.RunInitAndSetParametersAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task taskToHandle, ComponentState owningComponentState)
```

Here is the relevant code:

`IItemService.CS:`

```
Task<List<Item>> GetItemsByCategory(string category);
```

`ItemService.CS:`

```
public async Task<List<Item>> GetItemsByCategory(string category)
{
    List<Item>items = await _db.Items.Where(item => item.Category == category).ToListAsync();
    return items;
}
```

`ClientItemService.cs`

```
public async Task<List<Item>> GetItemsByCategory(string category)
{
    var result = await  _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>($"/api/Item/{category}");
    return result;
}
```

`ItemController.cs`

```
[HttpGet("{category}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> GetItemsByCategory(string category)
{
    var items = await _itemServices.GetItemsByCategory(category);
    return Ok(items);
}
```

Update:
this is the error i am getting:

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AmbiguousMatchException: The request matched multiple endpoints. Matches:

Design_A_Bear.Controllers.ItemController.GetItemsByCategory (Design_A_Bear)
Design_A_Bear.Controllers.ItemController.GetItemById (Design_A_Bear)
```

This is becuase i have two get functions which takes in a parameter. How can i select which one i want?

```
        public async Task<List<Item>> GetItemsByCategory(string category)
        {
            var result = await  _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Item>>($"/api/Item/{category}");
            return result;
        }

        public async Task<Item> GetItemById(int id)
        {
            var result = await _httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<Item>($"/api/Item/{id}");
            return result;
        }
```

Comment: The error indicates the service is failing which means either the url does not work or the logic in it is broken. Since it is a GET, can you just call the url directly from a browser and get data? And have you debugged to ensure it is the correct url?

Comment: i tried to do this but i just get a blank page with nothing on it. I also tried this with an api call that works and it returns json.

Comment: but both functions are written the same with the addition to category

Comment: If you need to differentiate between the two endpoints on the same controller, you need a route attribute. Above each endpoint add 
`[Route("category/{category}"]` and `[Route("id/{id}"]` or something along those lines. That will allow the methods be differentiated since they both appear to be GET endpoints on the same controller. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: Also for the sake of testing and ensuring that at least one endpoint works completely, it might help to comment out the second method for now and get the first method working. Then working on the routing of the two endpoints after each one works.

Comment: that worked thanks if you create an answer for it i can mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To differentiate between the two GET endpoints on the same controller, you need to add routing to each endpoint.

For the first endpoint

```
[Route("category/{category}")]
```

and for the second endpoint

```
[Route("items/{id}")]
```

something along these lines above the controller methods should solve the issue of having two GET endpoints.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2